# How do I fix a Address Boundary Error in C

Tags: c, runtime-error

I'm writing a program that takes 2 command line arguments which are each pointers to strings. I call them str and except. If there's a lower case letter in str then it's an error and the program ends. If a char is in str but not in except then it prints. I'm getting this error message when I run my code: “./a.out” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Comment: Seg fault means some invalid memory is being accessed. To fix the bug you need to first find it. To find such bugs (and many other types) run the program in a debugger. At a minimum it will tell you immediately and exactly which line of code triggers the seg fault. The debugger can also be used to step thru the code and examine state as it runs.

Comment: Are you really just running `./a.out` without any args? The program expects two args and since the code does no sanity checks for the number of args then it will access invalid memory if not enough args are provided. Make the code more robust by checking for the required number of args before proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIGSEGV will be shown when you don't put argv[2] or argv[1].
Please test

> ./a thistest et

And, your code means if there are lower case letters, it will pass.(your task is to except if there are lower case letters)

please repair :  `if((str[i] < 'A')||(str[i] > 'Z')){`